# Windows Authentication using MVC5, display Username at the top of every View

Tags: windows, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a MVC5 application for the DOE. We use windows authentication to login to our computers. I need help getting the users Name when logged in to be display "Welcome, Username"(across all pages) when they navigate to site. My problem is that when I navigate to the page it displays our ID which is what we use to login, i.e. i5456 and password. It would be much appreciated if someone would assist me and walk me through how to set this up.

I have already disabled Forms auth and enabled windows auth in VS 2013. I have tried using @User.Identity.Name in my SiteLayout, but like I said the ID is the only thing displayed. I'm not sure how to setup my model or view, or if I even have to. Is there a way to retrieve the Username so it can be displayed instead of the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this @User.Identity.GetUserName() in your view
works for me

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion but I get an error stating I'm missing a using directive or an assembly. Is this supposed to be used with a database? My problem is we aren't connected to the db because it is still live. I'm wondering is there a way to pull the username from the computer/server itself, without needing to be connected to the user database? Thanks again!